# Android Is it possible to change how dialog looks?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

> [image]

I would like the dialog asking for permissions to be full-screen, is it possible ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I'm not an android programmer, I just want to know what's possible to know the limits and what can I ask from developers.

Answer (score 1):

try

Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen)

this will set dialog to show with full screen.

Answer (score 0):

(if I understand your question properly...)

I do not think that we have control over how the Android Manifest Permissions are shown to the user.

As far as I am aware, this is done by the Google Play Store app, and is based only on the permissions declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dialog boxes.
There are answers already available on stackoverflow.

Check this - 
[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Comment: Does it work for system permissions (for example VPN permission in the screenshot) ?

Comment: All dialogs that appear in the app can be customized by a theme which can be set in the android manifest.      <activity android:name=".AndroidThemeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"      
>   But only theme can be changed. You cant change the contents of the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

create an activity and set its theme as dialog

Comment: Does it work for system permissions (for example VPN permission in the screenshot) ?